# d3 choropleth map having problems with filling colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I followed Mike Bostock choropleth example trying to make a world population choropleth map but I'm having trouble filling in colors correctly.

Here's my code and my data:
http://bl.ocks.org/jeremycflin/572ca92be1dfe68ac0d3

Really, any answers or help that can take me to the right direction will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and data, rather than linking to it. Should the link die it'll be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a different scale? China has quite a lot of people, pushing most of the countries to lower segments.

Everyone starting from place 4 will be at the lowest segment.

```
quantize(1330141295) // China
>"q8-9"

quantize(1173108018) // India
>"q7-9"

quantize(310232863) // United States
>"q2-9"

quantize(242968342) // Indonesia
>"q1-9"

quantize(201103330) // brazil
>"q1-9"
```

If you replace your maximum from the scale with for example the population of brazil you'll see that there will be more colors used.

```
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
        .domain([0,201103330])
        .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));
```

You could also use [the quantile scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantile-scales) to utilize all segments.

Comment: It doesn't just divid the whole list nine four segments?

Comment: If you are asking what quantize does, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize-scales

Comment: Maybe you are confusing it with quantile.

Comment: It would be worth taking a log transform of your population data.

Comment: Thank you so much, i think i finally got it!